# PHP Array seen as single element in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have two arrays in PHP which I am trying to pass to a Chart to be displayed in Chartjs.

The following code creates the arrays by using a foreach on a multidimensional array to extract them.

```
<?php
    $behaviours = orderByType($_SESSION['loggedStudent']['studentID']);
    $behTypes = array();
    $behValues = array();
    foreach($behaviours as $item){
        $behTypes[] = $item["type"];
        $behValues[] = intval($item["count(*)"]);
    }
    // php arrays to JSON
    $behaviourLabels = json_encode($behTypes, TRUE); 
    $behaviourValues = json_encode($behValues, TRUE);
?>

<canvas id="pie-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>

<script>
// parse to js
var strLables = <?php echo($behaviourLabels); ?>;
var strValues = <?php echo($behaviourValues); ?>;

// parse as array
var arrLables = JSON.parse($strLables);
var arrValues = JSON.parse($strValues);

new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: arrLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Incident Type",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        data: arrValues,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Breakdown of incident types for <?php echo($_SESSION['loggedStudent']['firstName']);  ?>'
      }
    }
});

</script>
```

No chart or labels are showing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected values for both `data` and `labels` are array.

What you need to do is pass `json` to JavaScript.

```
// php arrays to JSON
$behaviourLabels = json_encode($behTypes);
$behaviourValues = json_encode($behValues);
```

Now in javascript

```
var arrLables = <?php echo($behaviourLabels); ?>;
var arrValues = <?php echo($behaviourValues); ?>;

// Now use them directly in you configuration
data: {
      labels: arrLables,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Incident Type",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        data: arrValues,
      }]
    },
```

Comment: I have done this but now nothing is showing, no chart or labels. I have updated my original question. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm also a little confused as to why the $ symbol is used in JS at the top of your JavaScript

Comment: first section was php code not javascript and in second we're passing value from php variable to javascript variable.

Comment: oh i'm really sorry that is wrong, i mistakenly did that. Updated my answer. and verify whether you're getting data in `strLables` and `strValues` by using `console.log(strLables, strValues)`

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a JSON parse error. "JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Classwork"". I guess it's having trouble parsing the array for some reason. Which would explain why I was having the problem in the first place

Comment: try enclosing them into a double quote.

Comment: Sorry, enclosing what in to a double quote?

Comment: According to the console, the values are  var strLables = ["Classwork","Bullying"];
var strValues = [3,1];

Comment: see this `var strLables = "<?php echo($behaviourLabels); ?>";` and its below line. both are now enclosed in double quote. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: may be you're getting error due to double quote. Let me give you one more subtle solution. Give me some time

Comment: It's fixed now. The solution was to pass the JS variables straight in to the Chart. Didn't need to parse them as an array with JSON. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I mean, reparse them. The PHP line still needed to do that but not the parsing in the JS

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just verify. So anybody looking for such issue, can look here for reference.